# Are airline prices to Paris impacted by Valentine's Day, i.e. would the prices drop after Valentine's Day (June trip planning now)?

Tags: air-travel, paris, price, flight-search-engines

I guess this question could be asked in regards to all airfares purchased in the weeks prior to Valentine's Day, but I specifically wonder about flights purchased to Paris because of it's romantic draw and notoriety.

I'm trying to plan a trip to France in mid June, and I'm looking at flights. *I'm just planning a family vacation, but it just so happens to be around Valentine's Day that I'm planning. haha*

**I was curious if flights to Paris are impacted in any way by purchasing-time in relation to Valentine's Day** (going off an assumption that some super romantics out their might surprise their loves with tickets to Paris on Valentine's Day -- to be used this year)?

**Would I expect prices to be cheaper after Valentine's Day?**

If so, how much after should I wait?

And how much of a difference are we looking at here?

*I know no one can predict the costs of flights, but I was wondering if there is a known pattern in past history?*

Or not really?

The prices should be about the same?

Comment: I suppose it's vaguely plausible ... but I doubt the number of "romantic" purchasers buying journeys departing anytime over the year would make it worth an airline inflating its price above the otherwise expected market price, and thereby discouraging other, non-romantic purchasers. You can set a Google Flights alert to collect some statistics on it.

Comment: @pnuts, yes, February 14th as Valentine's Day.

Comment: @Calchas, could you maybe point me in the direction of how I can learn to do a Google Flights alert?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  But even if so, not enough to meaningfully impact most people travel plans.  Meaning, the price isn't going to fluctuate 20% due to Valentine's day.  It's not something I would have even though of.

Comment: @ButterflyandBones If you set up a search on www.google.com/flights, you should see an option to "Track Prices" appear. Type in your email and you will be emailed if it drops in prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a brief look at the public tariffs for Chicago-Paris as published by American Airlines, Air France and Lufthansa. This will be fairly representative as these three represent the major three groups who now control prices across the Atlantic. I compared the historical tariff as was in effect back in mid November 2016, the tariff in effect today, and the tariff presently scheduled to be effective on the 15th of February 2017.

Just looking at the lowest fares possible, which will not be available on all flights, if anything the price has dropped since November and that lower price remains in effect forward to the 15th of February.

The airlines can always launch a surprise sale which would bring the price down, and with a bit of work they can withdraw fares unexpectedly at about an hour's notice. They can also tinker with availability on any flights with instant effect (to prevent the cheapest fares being used on some of their flights). But an across-the-board price decrease does not appear to be on the horizon and the current fares do not seem to be time-limited.

Still we will see how good my predictions are next week.